# Issue with AMR file structure

Tags: audio

For developing an application I have to identify a region of sound. But I’m not sure if I have my basic knowledge right. I’m using AMR-NB sound clips to identify a sound region. According to my understanding AMR files have 160 samples for each 20ms (milliseconds) making it 800 sample for 1 minute. I am basing my complete dependence on this concept. Please let me know whether this is correct if not please correct me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say that you are trying to "identify a sound region", are you trying to find out in a given frame of signal, whether the frame has voice or silence ? If not can you rephrase your question with more details ?

Comment: Welcome to DSP.SE. Please don't put questions for the OP (user asking a question) in the "Answer" field. Those are expected to be actual answers. You can ask additional questions by commenting on the question. You can do that once you're achieved sufficient reputation on the site. You can read the FAQ(http://dsp.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, if it's got 160 samples every 20ms, you get a sampling rate of 8000 (you're missing a zero), which is the standard for over-the-phone voice communication. from a Google search, I couldn't find any AMR-NB specification that uses a different sampling rate.

Also, I found this line [here](http://forum.doom9.org/archive/index.php/t-85426.html) pretty useful:

> For AMR-NB, only an “8000” sample rate and one of the following
>   bitrates are valid:
>   4.75k, 5.15k, 5.9k, 6.7k, 7.4k, 7.95k, 10.2k or 12.2k

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptive_Multi-Rate_audio_codec#Usage) also mentions that AMR-NB uses a 8000 Hz sampling rate, you can be pretty sure that this is the case all across the board.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing that. Now the problem that I have is this clip that I explained is 5 seconds long. But the byte stream only reads 8000 samples(Bytes) where it must read 40000 samples. Is there a reason for this? Or can there be anything wrong in my code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "byte stream only reads...". Are you using specific software to do this?

Comment: Im reading it using a dataInput stream into a byte array. Where i must get 40000 samples. But im only getting 8000 samples. Is there a reason for this. Thanks

Comment: How are you doing it? What programming language are you using? Is this a software tool? How are you calling it? I really have no idea. Perhaps, this should be a good separate question on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: Im doing thi in java. The normal way that a file is read."FileIn = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(FilePath))"

Comment: If i can get a reason for this error i would be most thankful.

Comment: If it's a Java issue, you should ask a separate question on Stack Overflow.